# How do i load javascript code with django tags into my django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

Situation: I'm using Django 1.9. And i have a javascript loop that takes some javascript stored in database. This js has some django tags that i want to load when that js is loaded into my template.
This is the function:

```
{% extends "base_clean.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Campaign" %} - {{ campaign.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


Some HTML

Some CSS

<script type="text/javascript">

Some javascript functions.

displayed = 0;
delay = 1000;
(function loop() {
   setTimeout(function() {
   p = pq.getMessage()
   if( p != false ) {
      posthtml = get_message_html(p);
      displayed++;

       {{ display_style.layout.js|safe }} /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/


   if( pq.messagesCount() < 10 ){
      pq.getMessages()
   }
   loop();
 }, delay);
})();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is what {{ display_style.layout.js|safe }} load:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#messages_container').append(posthtml);
        {% if display_style.post_append_effect %}
          $(posthtml).addClass("animated {{ display_style.post_append_effect.css }}");
        {% endif %}
      }, 900);
    }

    if(displayed == {{ display_style.messages_per_page }}){
        delay = {{ display_style.seconds_between_messages }}000;
    }

    if(displayed > {{ display_style.messages_per_page }}){
      $target = $('#messages_container div.list-group-item').first()
      {% if display_style.message_remove_effect %}
        $target.removeClass("animated {{ display_style.post_append_effect.css }}")
        .addClass("animated {{ display_style.post_remove_effect.css }}");
      {% endif %}
      setTimeout(function() {
        $target.remove();
        displayed--
      }, 900);

    }
```

As you can see it has some django tags that i also want to render. But i've got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %"

EDIT: Added django header tags. and structure of the templates
And forgot to say that if i write explicitly the js that i want to render to my template it works... problem is trying to render tags into the rendered js

Comment: The issue isn't in the code you're showing, but you aren't showing everything. Please show the rest of your template and the rest of the error trace.

Comment: Ok, I'll simplify the template file because is very big.. ill just put what its involved here.
And about the error trace its just that... i mean, chrome dev tools put an error at the first "{% if display_style.post_append_effect %}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're loading a second template as a text string rather than using Django's [`include` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include). Try changing `{{ display_style.layout.js|safe }}` to `{% include "display_style.layout.js" %}` and any syntax error should become more apparent.

You should also consider using Django's staticfiles to load your javascript rather than including javascript in your template. Then per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4254358/2532070) you can simply define the variables you want to pass to your javascript in a `<script>` tag that you can reference in your javascript file. Something like:

## Django template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Some html -->
<script>
    var displayStyle = {{ display_style }};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'your_js_file.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Rest of your HTML -->
```

## JS file loaded via staticfiles

```
var displayStyle = window.displayStyle || null;
if (displayStyle) {
    // Your code here.
}
```

Last, one possibility for the specific error is that your included template has a `%` character somewhere. This would need to be escaped as `%%` in the django templating system.

Comment: I'll try the staticfiles way.
I'm still unable to load "dynamically" the js..
I gotta say what is the purpose of this and maybe you can have a hint on what should i do. 
It must take html, css and javascript of a layout for showing messages. So i shoul be able to "plug" and "unplug" attached html/css/js that the layout has. I've already did html and css part. Problem is in the js  

PS: Thanks @YPCrumble for answer

Comment: @Ctrl4 you shouldn't have to "unplug" the javascript - most likely there's a way to make the same JS code work for different iterations of your html. One more question - don't you have an extra `}` on the fifth line of that code after the first `setTimeout` function?

Comment: Actually i was thinking all bad... I was mixing django templates with mustache js but i was "unplugging" the js in a bad way. As you saw i had an extra } but it was part of this missthinking of mine.

I did it and was thanks to your answer about using static files.